# Using YouTube as hosting platform to embed videos with download functionality?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I need to embed videos in my android/ios app and I'm thinking about using Youtube as the hosting platform. Besides just playing the videos, it should be possible to download certain videos.

I know apps for downloading youtube videos are not allowed but in my case, a user cannot download any videos he wants, just the ones I embedded (from my youtube cannel). Would this use case be allowed in the app stores?

Also are there other disadvantages for using youtube as a hosting service to embed videos?

Comment: One disadvantage would be privacy, if that’s something you or your users care about.

Comment: @KevSlashNull what exactly do you mean by that? What data is google collecting when using the youtube api?

Comment: I wasn’t talking about the YouTube API, I mean embedding YouTube videos directly is a privacy concern. As for what data Google is collecting, only Google knows. It’s a black box for us but you can read through their [privacy policy](http://www.google.com/policies/privacy) and decide for yourself.